# c# - DataGridView to txt...Header and first row on same line issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, visual-c#-express-2010

I am attempting to export data from a datagridview into a .txt table of sorts.

When I export to the .txt, the header prints on the first line like it is supposed too, but the first row of the table prints on that line too...Now I have tried a number of things but, obviously my logic is very wrong here.

I basically want a way to set *dataGridView_Excel.Rows.Count - 1;* to just the normal count without the -1. But every time I do it throws a **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** Or if I try to increase the column count to counteract that I get a **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.** Any suggestions on how to do this better? I understand why its happening, my logic to fix it just isn't sound and I am beyond confused.

```
if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(save.OpenFile());

            int i2 = 0;
            while (i2 < 19)
            {
                writer.Write(dataGridView_Excel.Columns[i2].HeaderText + "\t        " + "|");
                i2++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_Excel.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {                                      
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView_Excel.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    writer.Write("\t" + dataGridView_Excel.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t        " + "|");

                }

                writer.WriteLine("");
                writer.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            writer.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a case of looking at something too long and getting distracted...oops

Here is the easiest way around this:

```
if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(save.OpenFile());

            int i2 = 0;
            while (i2 < 20)
            {
                writer.Write(dataGridView_Excel.Columns[i2].HeaderText + "\t        " + "|");
                i2++;
            }

            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_Excel.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {                                      
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView_Excel.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    writer.Write("\t" + dataGridView_Excel.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t        " + "|");

                }

                writer.WriteLine("");
                writer.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            writer.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
        }
```

I just added a Environment.NewLine and my ---- divider before the loop. The whole reason I added the Header to the file in a while loop outside the main for loop was for easy changes down the road to the .txt format. Thank you for the idea @ainwood it set me back on track!

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hHQq.jpg)

[After!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEjaC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your DataGridView is 0-indexed and has 'count' total rows.  This line:
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_Excel.Rows.Count - 1; i++)

Will start at zero and go to the ((numbers of rows -1)-1), because it is **<**:  Less than.

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView_Excel.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
```

i.e. add in the = sign, or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_Excel.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Unless I've misunderstood your issue.  Is the issue the looping, or is it getting things to write on a new line?

To get it to write a new line, try adding Environment.NewLine to the end:

```
writer.Write("\t" + dataGridView_Excel.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t        " + "|" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: When I do <= or I remove the -1 completely I get the **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** because the number of rows is no longer less than the number of columns and they become equal. Here are pictures of my issue: [link](http://i.imgur.com/WuSzwgv.jpg) [link](http://i.imgur.com/4LkRKmH.jpg) [link](http://i.imgur.com/sHKpbq4.jpg) [link](http://i.imgur.com/ppg0P4v.jpg) So my header line and my 1st row of the datagridview combine on export to .txt. I had already tried doing what you suggested, but it does not work.

Comment: Thank you for the Newline suggestion and for the response!